# privacypolicy and security settings

Tags: security, privacy

I'm new to all this so please be patient with me. I should have made this effort awhile back but I didn't, I'm just learning about technology actually, I haven't had the best of luck lately but honestly I hope I can chat and find answers with others and I hope you can accept me as just a beginner. Anyway, thanks..

Constantly reading permissions and how to clean up the mess I'm in and get a new fresh start.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.